# SQl query datetime from nvarchar error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL,

```
declare @date datetime ='Jul15' 
select CONVERT(varchar(10),@date,105)
```

getting error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is because `Jul15` is not a valid SQL Server `Date` or `DateTime` value, hence the error when it is trying to convert it to date/datetime to assign it to a datetime variable.

Ideally you should be using ANSI-Standard when working with date or datetime values in SQL Server, ANSI-Standard `Date` value has the format of `YYYYMMDD`, therefore your statement should look something like this.....

```
declare @date datetime ='20150701' 
select CONVERT(varchar(10),@date,105)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my requirement is like we will be getting input as 'mmmyy' and we need to save it in date datatype column. so i am getting the above error. ?

Comment: SQL Server requires a complete date value with Years, Month and Days in it, in order to accept it as a valid date/datetime value, if you are getting only `MMMYY` values you cannot store them in a date/datetime column in sql server you will need to use a varchar column for that.